# How to call a function properly with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, appery.io

I've built an app with Appery and I have just one little function that doesn't appear to work correctly when I export the app and install it and test it.

The intended function is to be called "onclick" and when it happens, it's supposed to call the restful api service called dovoiceDelete.execute();

Here's the code:

```
var doDel = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this voicemail?");


if(doDel === true){

    dovoiceDelete.execute();
}
```

The issue is, within the app, when you click on the button, nothing happens. The call doesn't get executed - and the confirmation window doesn't open up.

Not quite sure why - as this is pretty straight forward javascript, and not sure why it's not being executed properly.

If it matters, Appery builds hybrid HTML5/jQuery style apps and my app is just that.

Comment: also share a code which you used on button click

Comment: How about use `if (confirm("Are you sure...") == true) { `

Comment: We need to see more of the relevant code to see what is going wrong.  The part you show works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5shLL4vv/

Comment: this code is ok... the problem should be in the HTML of the button that calls this function.

Comment: @DanielWilliams Since it's never even displaying the confirmation dialogue, it doesn't matter how he writes the `if`.

Comment: The code works well, please use alert instead of dovoiceDelete.execute() here to see the results. It seems that data service doesn't exist on this page